# How to prove that the median and angle bisector are not the same for non-isoceles triangles.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, triangles

I can prove that if the median and angle bisector are the same, then the triangle must be isosceles.

How can I prove that the median and angle bisector are not the same for non-isoceles triangles?

Assume triangle ABC with median AD and angle bisector AE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can prove that by contradiction, for example.

Comment: use angle bisector theorem

Answer (score 0):

Using known expressions for
median $m_a$ and
corresponding bisector $\beta_a$

\begin{align} 
m_a^2 &= \tfrac12 b^2+\tfrac12 c^2-\tfrac14 a^2
,\\
\beta_a^2 &= bc \left(1-\frac{a^2}{(b+c)^2}\right)
,
\end{align}

to get them of the same length, we must have
\begin{align}
\tfrac12 b^2+\tfrac12 c^2-\tfrac14 a^2
-
bc \left(1-\frac{a^2}{(b+c)^2}\right)
&=0
,\\
\frac{(b-c)^2(2(b+c)^2-a^2)}{4(b+c)^2}&=0
,
\end{align}

which is true only when either
$a=\sqrt2(b+c)$, which never holds for triangles,
or $b=c$.

Answer (score 0):

The median $AI$ issued from vertex $A$ divides the opposite side $BC$ in two equal parts: $$\dfrac{IB}{IC}=1$$

The angle bisector $AJ$ of angle $\hat{A}$ divides the opposite side $BC$ into two segments whose lengths are in the same ratio as the adjacent sidelengths: $$\dfrac{JB}{JC}=\dfrac{AB}{AC}$$

([Angle bissector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem))

The conclusion is easy from there.

Comment: Any comment ?...